# adding mixing lines across all pressures in skewT metpy

Tags: python, metpy

I can plot a standard SkewT chart with mixing lines up to the default of p=600hPa, using the default call `plot_mixing_lines()`  But I wanted to extend them up to the upper troposphere.   I tried to do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from metpy.plots import SkewT
from metpy.units import units

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
skew=SkewT(fig)
skew.plot_moist_adiabats()
plevs=[ '1', '2', '3',
            '5', '7', '10',
            '20', '30', '50',
            '70', '100', '125',
            '150', '175', '200',
            '225', '250', '300',
            '350', '400', '450',
            '500', '550', '600',
            '650', '700', '750',
            '775', '800', '825',
            '850', '875', '900',
            '925', '950', '975',
            '1000']
plevs = units.Quantity(plevs,"hPa")
skew.plot_mixing_lines(pressure=plevs)
```

but that falls over with error:

```
~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pint/quantity.py in _mul_div(self, other, magnitude_op, units_op)
   1285                 return NotImplemented
   1286 
-> 1287             magnitude = magnitude_op(self._magnitude, other_magnitude)
   1288             units = units_op(self._units, self.UnitsContainer())
   1289 

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U4'), dtype('float64')) -> None
```

All the example usage I found online either didn't have mixing lines, or used the default. Am I doing something stupid?

Now on metpy 1.1, python 3.9.9 on Clang 13.0.0, and rolled back matplotllib to 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that all the values in `plevs` are strings rather than values. I fixed that up with a `plevs = list(map(int, plevs))`, but you might find it easier to try:

```
import numpy as np
plevs = np.logspace(0, 3, 100)
```

Which will give you 100 points spaced out logarithmically between 1 (10^0) and 1000 (10^3).

Comment: duh, I told you I was being stupid... I'm so used to lists of strings for CDS retrieval requests now that I don't even notice anymore... THANK YOU.